# Bounded form count not shown in textbox-MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Access which sorts queries with start date and end date. There are 4 different buttons A,B,C,D which have 4 textboxes beside them. Each of these button runs a query within the stipulated dates. I made another query named Count which counts the records in all the 4 queries. It has 4 fields named FieldA, FieldB, FieldC and Field D.

I made this Count query as the Record Source of the form and I added the fields FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD into the 4 text boxes. When I turn back into Form View or when I refresh the form the 4 textboxes are filled with `0 as a value`. Although in the Count Query their values are `20, 25, 56, 97`.

What could be the possible reason for it not to work? Why are the values not shown in the textboxes?

Comment: Where's your query SQL and button code. I wouldn't be using COUNT as a query name, table name or field name - it's a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

Tried to recreate your problem, my form does display the number of records correctly.
I have 4 queries based on some tables, and I created a Count query with the following SQL:

```
SELECT DCount("*","Query1") AS FieldA,
DCount("*","Query2") AS FieldB,
DCount("*","Query3") AS FieldC,
DCount("*","Query4") AS FieldD;
```

Then created form based on this Count query, the bound form displays the values correctly.

Then i grabbed one unbound form and set the recordsource to the query, and bound some textboxes to FieldA, B , C and D. the results were shown correctly.

The only thing I can infer from your problem is that your Count query is not correclty formulated.

Comment: The Count query which you have created uses DCount. It is very slow if there are more than 4000 records to Count. It gives me a lot of Performance issues to use DCount and that is why I shifted to Bound based form and I used a query similar to yours with Count(*) but when I drag those fields onto my form. They give me a 0 Value